# TensorFlow: Why does avg_pool ignore one stride dimension?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, max-pooling

I am attempting to stride over the channel dimension, and the following code exhibits surprising behaviour. It is my expectation that `tf.nn.max_pool` and `tf.nn.avg_pool` should produce tensors of identical shape when fed the exact same arguments. This is not the case.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.get_variable('x', shape=(100, 32, 32, 64),
        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(5), dtype=tf.float32)
ksize = (1, 2, 2, 2)
strides = (1, 2, 2, 2)
max_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize, strides, padding='SAME')
avg_pool = tf.nn.avg_pool(x, ksize, strides, padding='SAME')
print(max_pool.shape)
print(avg_pool.shape)
```

This prints

```
$ python ex04/mini.py 
(100, 16, 16, 32)
(100, 16, 16, 64)
```

Clearly, I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: I think it's a bug. If you open an issue on GitHub please link it here because I wanna watch the conversation, thank you

Comment: It seems like a bug. Alternatively, you can use slim, it performs well.

Comment: @DenizBeker What do you mean by _slim_?

Comment: @oarfish  You can check the details from here. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is really a bug.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14886#issuecomment-352934112

Answer (score 4):

The link https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/issues/19 states:

> The first and last stride must always be 1,
>     because the first is for the image-number and
>     the last is for the input-channel.

Comment: Clearly, _must_ is overstated then, since it just silently runs instead of erroring. It seems I must file a bug report.